# Would a lens error cause a camera to NOT power on at all?

Tags: lens, troubleshooting, sony

I have a Sony DSC-HX30V and there was sand in the lens gears.  I disassembled the camera, cleaned the lens and put it together. It didn't turn on.  I have tried tons of things and not sure what happened.

Really frustrating. I don't get ANY 'error' or anything, camera completely dead. I could buy a new lens unit which maybe was the problem but man...don't want to throw good money after bad, but don't want to trash camera if its on the verge of working.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible a lens error could do it, but there are several other possibilities that could cause the camera to not power up at all:

- In the process of disassembly/reassembly you may have loosened a power connection between the battery and the camera.
- You might have accidently disconnected the "power on" switch somewhere between the switch and the main PC board.
- You might have disturbed an "open door" switch that are usually placed on things like the battery compartment and memory card slot covers.
- You might have disconnected or loosened any other vital wiring connection that the camera needs to power up.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I have looked carefully for any 'kill switch' and dont see one.  I have plugged in all the wires multiple times.  It is just weird how utterly dead the thing is.